# How can i take a backup of an ArrayList in Java after i call .clear()?

Tags: java, variables

I'm programming in Java and I would like to take a backup of an `ArrayList`
before I clean it
Unfortunately, after I call `clear()`, the back up is cleaned as well.
How can I solve that?

My program is as follows:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayListMethod ALM = new ArrayListMethod();
    ALM.FillArrayList();

}

}
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListMethod {

public void FillArrayList() {

    ArrayList AL;
    AL =  new ArrayList();
    ArrayList BACKUPArrayList = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= 5; i++) {
        AL.add(i);
        BACKUPArrayList = AL;
        System.out.println(" ARRAY LIST BEFORE CLEAR " + AL);
        AL.clear();
    }
    System.out.println(" BACK UP LIST AFTER CLEAR" + BACKUPArrayList);
    //Unfortunately the BACKUPArrayList is cleaned as well...

}

}
```

Comment: Why are you clearing the list on each iteration? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: This is a sample of another program that i'm currently working on and i have included only a small part of it, im my real program in every iteration i concatenate 3 array lists in one single one and after that i clear them all in order to fill them again with values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your backup list is cleared as well is that in java all variables are references. This means that the line `BACKUPArrayList = AL;` doesnt copy the contents of `AL` to `BACKUPArrayList` but makes the variable (not object!) `BACKUPArrayList` references `AL`. So both `AL` and `BACKUPArrayList` reference the same list after that assignment.

To solve this simply call `BACKUPArrayList.addAll(AL);`. This line will add all elements of `AL` to `BACKUPArrayList`. See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html

Answer (score 4):

Try with collections copy:

```
Collections.copy(arrayList2,arrayList1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do backup by clone the original array list

```
BACKUPArrayList = AL.clone();
```