# How to retreive items back in arraylist once it is cleared: Android

Tags: android, arraylist, filter

I have an array list that displays a list of companies. Each of these companies is having corresponding town names. Further, I am creating buttons for each of the town names such that when I click on any of the town names, the ArrayList should be filtered and only the companies with that town name should be displayed.

The buttons are like,

```
    stringList.add(tempList.get(n).getTownName());
    btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 60));
    btnTag.setText(stringList.get(k));
    btnTag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alpha_button_selector);
    btnTag.setClickable(true);
    townLayout.addView(btnTag);
```

On clicking the button, I am fetching the text in the button as it displays the town name and then I am calling the method to filter the data,

```
        btnTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CharSequence name = btnTag.getText();
                locationFilter(name);
            }
        });
```

For filtering the data, I am creating a new ArrayList to store the filtered data such as,

```
        ArrayList<CompanySearchResult> filtered = new ArrayList<CompanySearchResult>();
            for (CompanySearchResult town : tempList) {

                if (town.getTownName().equals(name)) {
                    filtered.add(town);
                }
            }

            tempList.clear();
            tempList.addAll(filtered);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The data is getting filtered properly, but my issue here is when I filter the data for the first time, my tempList(which is the main ArrayList containing the data) gets updated by the contents of the filtered ArrayList.
Then when I click on the second button with another town name and try to filter that, it tries to filter the tempList which is already updated with the filtered data and the result displayed is blank.

Thus, how can I populate my tempList with the original data again each time a button with the town name is being clicked and then filter it out in a similar manner.

I have researched on this but couldn't find anything relevant. I have also tried the solution mentioned in the link:

- [android filter custom array adapter and bring back old items again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809585/android-filter-custom-array-adapter-and-bring-back-old-items-again)
- [How can i take a backup of an ArrayList in Java after i call .clear()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225609/how-can-i-take-a-backup-of-an-arraylist-in-java-after-i-call-clear)

However, it didn't help. can anyone please help on how can I achieve this?

Comment: can you share the method where you actually created/fetched tempList?

Comment: I am using the cursor for adding items in the tempList.

Comment: Also create one more list their exact same like tempList eg mainList and put tempList into that mainList.addAll(tempList) and then  use it .. (CompanySearchResult town : mainList)

Comment: @kulvinder I followed what u said and it's almost working as I expected. Can u add it as an answer so that I can accept the same as the solution?

Comment: my pleasure to solved this problem..  answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one more list(eg.mainList) where you created tempList and put tempList into that like this

```
mainList.addAll(tempList)
```

and then update this method like this

```
 ArrayList<CompanySearchResult> filtered = new ArrayList<CompanySearchResult>();
        for (CompanySearchResult town : mainList) {
            if (town.getTownName().equals(name)) {
                filtered.add(town);
            }
        }

        tempList.clear();
        tempList.addAll(filtered);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the original set of items in the adapter as a backup list.
The adapter should always only display the contents of the filtered list.

If you add data to the adapter, add them to the backup and filtered list.

When you click a button, clear the **filtered** list and then add only the matching items from the **backup** list to the **filtered list**.

```
public class SomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeAdapter.SomeViewHodler> {

static class SomeViewHodler extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public SomeViewHodler(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    void bind(String data) {
        // FIll views here
    }
}

private final List<String> displayedList = new ArrayList<>();

private final List<String> originalList = new ArrayList<>();

private String filterString = "";

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return displayedList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SomeViewHodler holder, final int position) {
    holder.bind(displayedList.get(position));
}

@Override
public SomeViewHodler onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.view, parent, false);
    return new SomeViewHodler(view);
}

/**
 * Call from outside to send data into this adapter
 */
public void replaceData(@NonNull final List<String> data) {
    // Store new data in original list
    originalList.clear();
    originalList.addAll(data);

    filter();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void filter() {
    // Clear display first
    displayedList.clear();

    // If filter is empty, show all items
    if (filterString == null || filterString.isEmpty()) {
        displayedList.addAll(originalList);
    } else {
        // if filter is not empty, check if item matches query
        for (String obj : originalList) {
            if (obj.contains(filterString)) {
                displayedList.add(obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It sounds good to me. But do u mind giving some code example on how can I achieve this exactly? Please bear with me.. new to android.

Answer (score 2):

@Traxdata answer is correct. Here is my explain in code

Modify your adapter like

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    YourAdapter(List<CompanySearchResult> filterList){

    }
}
```

In your `Activity`

`YourAdapter listAdapter = new YourAdapter(filterList);`

At first time you display the list

```
filterList = new ArrayList<>(tempList);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

When you filter

```
ArrayList < CompanySearchResult > filtered = new ArrayList < CompanySearchResult > ();
for (CompanySearchResult town: tempList) {
     if (town.getTownName().equals(name)) {
         filtered.add(town);
     }
}

filterList.clear();
filterList.addAll(filtered);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```